# Big-$O$ notation definition.

Tags: notation, definition

I have come across the notation

$$...+\ O_R(x)$$

where $R$ is any positive real number, and $R<2$. What is the term big $O_R$ of $x$ referring to?

Comment: I have no idea, but a wild guess would be that the term in question has absolute value at most $R|x|$. Where did you see this notation?

Comment: In the context this does make sense, but to what degree it is universally applicable, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, $A = B + O_R(x)$ means that for all $R$, there exists $C_R > 0$ such that for all $x$, $$|A-B| \leq C_R |x|.$$ Notice that $A$ and $B$ can be functions of $R$ and $x$. Depending on the context, the inequality may be required only for $x$ lying in some set, for $x$ large enough, for $x$ near enough $0$, etc.

Comment: What is $ C_R $ here?

Comment: @martin: $C_R$ is a positive real number.

Comment: So what is the relevance here of $ R <2 $? Is it as straightforward as Harold says above, or does it hold for some other positive real number?

Comment: For all $R < 2$, there exists a constant $C_R$ such that [...] Maybe $C_R = |R|$ or maybe $C_R = \pi+\sqrt{2}$ or maybe $C_R = e^{e^{R^2}}$... the $O_R(x)$ doesn't say.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Comment: Just out if interest then, why use $ O_R$ & not just $ O $?

Comment: To emphasize the lack of uniformity in R.